# modifying rows based on rowspans also modified using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a table having two section. The first section has 4 row 
and the second section has 3 rows. I append a `td` to the first section with 
row span 4 and to the second section with row span 3. I want to append row span dynamically to each section using jQuery, based on the rows from the 
database for each section. I append row span based on first row in each section. The issue is: when I delete rows from the bottom it works properly, but when I remove rows from middle row span is not appending correctly. Please help me to solve this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_table').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
  $('td').click(function() {
    var row_index = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(row_index, 'my');

    if (row_index == 1) {
      console.log(row_index, 'if');
      rowspan = '3' > Appended item < /td>" );
      $('table tr').eq(2).attr({
        name: 'first'
      });
      $("tr[name='first'] td:last-child").after("<td rowspan='3'>Appended item</td>");
    }
    if (row_index == 5) {
      console.log(row_index, 'if');
      $('table tr').eq(6).attr({
        name: 'second'
      });
      $("tr[name='first'] td:last-child").after("<td rowspan='2'>Appended item</td>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Tokens</td>
    <td>action</td>
    <td>social</td>
  </tr>
  <tr name="first">
    <td>ins_Ram</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
    <td rowspan="4">social</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ins_sam</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ins_dam</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ins_vam</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr name="second">
    <td>twt_Ram</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
    <td rowspan="4">social</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>twt_sam</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>twt_dam</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give one suggestion for your issue.I am using class and id to modify table row and row span.

```
           <table id="my_table">
              <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Tokens</td>
                <td>action</td>
                <td>social</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="first" id="1">
                <td>ins_Ram</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
                <td rowspan="4" class="first_rowspan">social</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="first" id="2">
                <td>ins_sam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>

              </tr>
              <tr class="first" id="3">
                <td>ins_dam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><button class="delete" >delete</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="first" id="4">
                <td>ins_vam</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td><button class="delete" >delete</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="second" id="5">
                <td>twt_Ram</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td><button class="delete" >delete</button></td>
                <td rowspan="4" class="second_rowspan">social</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="second" id="6">
                <td>twt_sam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td><button class="delete" >delete</button></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="second" id="7">
                <td>twt_dam</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td><button class="delete" >delete</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#my_table").on("click", ".delete", function() {
                    //alert($(this).parent().parent().prop('className'));

                    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                    var tr_class = $(this).parent().parent().prop('className');
                    $("#"+id).remove();
                var allClass = document.getElementsByClassName(tr_class);
                var lnth     = allClass.length;
                var rowspan  = document.getElementsByClassName(tr_class+'_rowspan');
                var rowspan_class = tr_class+'_rowspan';    
                //alert(lnth+' '+);
                    if(lnth>0 && rowspan.length>0){
                         $('.'+rowspan_class).attr("rowspan", lnth);   
                    }else if(lnth>0 && rowspan.length==0){
                        //alert(allClass[0].id);
                        $("tr#"+allClass[0].id+" > td:last").after('<td 
                 class="'+rowspan_class+'" rowspan="'+lnth+'">Social</td>');
                    }else{}
                });
            });
            </script>
```